# Event binding lost when page not fully loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events

Suppose I have a pretty large HTML page which uses jQuery `document.ready()` towards the end of the page to set up various element bindings. We have some impatient users who ignore the green progress bar at the bottom of the window (in IE) and start to interact with the page. In this particular case, they spent about an hour changing some dropdowns (with save events attached to them) only to be dissapointed that they lost time because of their impatience.

What are some techniques used to address this?

Comment: Make the page load faster (reduce the size of the dom and scripts), add a loading indicator and overlay that prevents the user from touching the page till it's done, or execute the javascript that binds the events sooner than dom ready, such as immediately after the form.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get round this any other way I recomend the block UI jquery component http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Simply call $.blockUI() to block the UI once ready you then call $.unBlockUI()